# python scipy.signal.peak_widths --> absolute heigth? (fft -3dB damping)

Tags: python, scipy

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_widths.html

I think the linked function can only calculate the peak widths at a relative height. Does anyone know if there is a function that calculates the width at a fixed value (peak_amplitude - x) for all peaks?

Currently I am trying to change the original inner function "_peak_widths". Fail already with the cimport. Understand the source code here only partially. I added in the code where I would make a modification.

```
 with nogil:
    for p in range(peaks.shape[0]):
        i_min = left_bases[p]
        i_max = right_bases[p]
        peak = peaks[p]
        # Validate bounds and order
        if not 0 <= i_min <= peak <= i_max < x.shape[0]:
            with gil:
                raise ValueError("prominence data is invalid for peak {}"
                                 .format(peak))
        height = width_heights[p] = x[peak] - prominences[p] * rel_height
```

## CHANGE HERE TO x[peak] - 3

```
        # Find intersection point on left side
        i = peak
        while i_min < i and height < x[i]:
            i -= 1
        left_ip = <np.float64_t>i
        if x[i] < height:
            # Interpolate if true intersection height is between samples
            left_ip += (height - x[i]) / (x[i + 1] - x[i])

        # Find intersection point on right side
        i = peak
        while i < i_max and height < x[i]:
            i += 1
        right_ip = <np.float64_t>i
        if  x[i] < height:
            # Interpolate if true intersection height is between samples
            right_ip -= (height - x[i]) / (x[i - 1] - x[i])

        widths[p] = right_ip - left_ip
        if widths[p] == 0:
            show_warning = True
        left_ips[p] = left_ip
        right_ips[p] = right_ip
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case this is still relevant to you, you can use [scipy.signal.peak_widths](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_widths.html) "as is" to achieve what you want by passing in modified `prominence_data`. Based on your own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53780811/8483989):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_prominences, peak_widths

# Create sample data
x = np.linspace(0, 6 * np.pi, 1000)
x = np.sin(x) + 0.6 * np.sin(2.6 * x)

# Find peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x)
prominences, left_bases, right_bases = peak_prominences(x, peaks)
```

As stated in `peak_widths`'s documentation the height at which the width is measured is calculated as 
`h_eval = h_peak - prominence * relative_height`

We can control the latter two variables through the parameters `prominence_data` and `rel_height`. So instead of passing in the calculated `prominence` which differs for each peak we can create an array where all values are the same and use that to create an absolute height:

```py
# Create constant offset as a replacement for prominences
offset = np.ones_like(prominences)

# Calculate widths at x[peaks] - offset * rel_height
widths, h_eval, left_ips, right_ips = peak_widths(
    x, peaks, 
    rel_height=1,
    prominence_data=(offset, left_bases, right_bases)
)

# Check that h_eval is 1 everywhere
np.testing.assert_equal(x[peaks] - h_eval, 1)

# Visualize result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
plt.hlines(h_eval, left_ips, right_ips, color="C2")
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see the width is evaluated for each peak at the same constant offset of 1. By using the original `left_bases` and `right_bases` as provided by `peak_prominences` we are limiting the maximal measured width (e.g. see peaks at 299 and 533). If you want to remove that limitation you must create these arrays yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the c content. Thats my solution:

```
def gauss(x, p): # p[0]==mean, p[1]==stdev
    return 1.0/(p[1]*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(x-p[0])**2/(2*p[1]**2))

def _peak_widths(x,peaks,prop,val=3):

    i_min = prop['left_bases']
    i_max = prop['right_bases']
    peak = peaks[0]
    # Validate bounds and order
    height = x[peak] - val

    # Find intersection point on left side
    i = peak
    while i_min < i and height < x[i]:
        i -= 1
    left_ip = i
    if x[i] < height:
        # Interpolate if true intersection height is between samples
        left_ip += (height - x[i]) / (x[i + 1] - x[i])

    # Find intersection point on right side
    i = peak
    while i < i_max and height < x[i]:
        i += 1
    right_ip = i
    if  x[i] < height:
        # Interpolate if true intersection height is between samples
        right_ip -= (height - x[i]) / (x[i - 1] - x[i])

    widths = right_ip - left_ip
    left_ips = left_ip
    right_ips = right_ip

    return [height, widths, int(left_ips), int(right_ips)]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create some sample data
    known_param = np.array([2.0, 0.07])
    xmin,xmax = -1.0, 5.0
    N = 1000
    X = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,N)
    Y = gauss(X, known_param)
    fig, ax= plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(X,Y)

    #find peaks
    peaks, prop = signal.find_peaks(Y, prominence = 3.1)
    ax.scatter(X[peaks],Y[peaks], color='r')

    #calculate peak width
    y, widths, x1, x2 = _peak_widths(Y,peaks, prop)

    print(f'width = { X[x1] - X[x2]}')

    l = mlines.Line2D([X[x1],X[x2]], [y,y], color='r')
    ax.add_line(l)
    plt.show()
```